# Unwind using UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making an app on which I use a TableView, for example, one of movies. Which cell when selected should return to the right view of the movie. The table view is divided in sections, so this is how I'm doing the unwind

```
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToAntMan" sender:self];
} else if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToF4" sender:self];
} else if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToDeadpool" sender:self];
} else if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToBatmanVSuperman" sender:self];
}
```

Also, each view is allowed to check the list anytime with a simple swipe, no problem there. But if I swipe from the first view, that here would be Ant Man, I can't select any view that comes after it. So if I select the next one which is F4, I can select both Ant Man and F4 cells, but not Deadpool.

I have no idea what's wrong or how to fix it, I'm pretty sure it's right at my face.

Comment: I think it is because I can only unwind to created views. Would that be right ?

Comment: You can only unwind to a *view controller* that had previously been on screen, and presented or pushed the controllers that eventually ended up at the controller where your code is.

Comment: How could I do that instead ? I thought of using a regular segue, but it's not working either

Comment: It is working now, but I believe I'm adding views over and over to the stack

Comment: You should not go back to a previous controller with anything other than an unwind. If you do, you're actually creating new instances, not "going back".